# \colon for maps in opposite direction

Tags: math-mode, spacing

Using `\colon` gives correct spacing for a map `$F\colon C\to D$` in one direction. But writing `$L\colon C\rightleftarrows D\colon R$` for a couple of maps in both directions (e.g. for an adjunction) gives disturbingly asymmetric spaces near first and second colons (like if D were a map from R, not the other way round). Probably, it should be fixed (e.g. some other command should be used) — but how?

Comment: Don't use \colon then. It is _defined_ to have small spacing on the left and big spacing on the right. Maybe you should dig into the code and find the definition for \colon and define a command like \rcolon that swaps the spacing before and after and use that.

Comment: @Willie: yes, I'm looking for some command \rcolon (\cocolon ;-)?), exactly — hopefully it's already defined and there's no need to invent a bicycle.

Comment: Surely not `\cocolon`!  It should be just `\lon` (and the opposite of the coefficient ring should be ...).

Comment: Why is `\colon` preferred over `:`?  I just checked a random sample of books in my office and the overwhelming majority uses the symmetrical spacing of `:`.  The exceptions (among the 15 or so books I checked) are Atiyah-MacDonald, Besse and Kobayashi-Nomizu.  I have to admit that I never sat down to think about this before.

Comment: I think it is also something semantical in addition to spacing. : is interpreted as a relation (I guess the ratio). At least that's what the _AMS Short Math Guide_ ftp://ftp.ams.org/pub/tex/doc/amsmath/short-math-guide.pdf suggests to me.

Comment: Yes, I understand and agree that there is a semantic distinction.  Alas, I find $f:A\to B$ much easier to parse (in the source) than $f\colon A \to B$, not to mention easier to type.  So will not be using `\colon` any time soon :(

Comment: @José Figueroa-O'Farrill: you could try defining a three-argument command `\fcn{f}{A}{B}` that expands to `f \colon A \to B`. I bet there are people who would say this is easier to parse in the source than `f:A\to B`, though I don't know that I'm one of them.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

`amsmath` defines `\colon` as `\nobreak \muskip 2mu\mathpunct{}\nonscript\mkern-\thinmuskip{:}\mskip 6mu plus1mu\relax`. So how about the following?

```
\newcommand*\cocolon{%
        \nobreak
        \mskip6mu plus1mu
        \mathpunct{}%
        \nonscript
        \mkern-\thinmuskip
        {:}%
        \mskip2mu
        \relax
}
```

Comment: works in simple cases (so I've accepted the answer), but try e.g. `\[\sin\colon X\rightleftarrows Y\cocolon\cos\]` — the space between \cocolon and mathop is too big

Comment: @Grigory M I found we can easily obtain what you want, by adding `\!`, to be ...`{:}\!`...

Comment: missed opportunity to simply call it `\lon`.