# Mirror-image \colon?

Tags: math-mode, spacing

I would like to typeset something like

> f \colon X \leftrightarrows \mcolon g

where `\mcolon` is a mirror-image of `\colon` as regards spacing. How would I do this?

Comment: See http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/2300/colon-for-maps-in-opposite-direction?rq=1

Comment: @ThomasF.Sturm - ok, thanks. I couldn't find that on a first pass.